# Can Minesweeper be played using the keyboard?

Tags: minesweeper

Can Minesweeper be played using a keyboard, like in Weird Al's "White and Nerdy"?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According [to Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/83274):

> The Minesweeper game provided with
>   Microsoft Windows operating system
>   version 3.1 or in the Windows
>   Entertainment Pack version 1 **cannot be**
>    **played without a mouse** unless you
>   install the Trace Access Pack for
>   Windows. With the Trace Access Pack
>   installed you can use the numeric
>   keypad to move the mouse.

In later versions of Windows, you can use [MouseKeys](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Use-Mouse-Keys-to-move-the-mouse-pointer) to use the numeric keypad to move the mouse.

However, a [minesweeper wiki article](http://www.minesweeper.info/wiki/Windows_Minesweeper#Keyboard) indicates that **versions of Minesweeper included with Vista or later operating systems have keyboard support**:

> In Vista or later it is easier to skip
>   MouseKeys and just use the keyboard.
>   Arrow keys move the cursor one square
>   at a time. Hit [Enter] to click, press
>   1 to flag and [Shift][Enter] to
>   chord. It is also possible to use
>   [Spacebar] to click, [Shift][Spacebar]
>   to flag or chord. In all versions [F2]
>   starts a new game and [Alt] allows you
>   to view the menus.